# How to print out SQL query results of TFS test records, in C#?

Tags: c#, sql, tfs

I need help in printing out results of query in TFS.

I am running code to get test case and test execution records from TFS. 
The extract works and I get the list of all the work item, with all the associated information.

I figured how to print out standard TFS fields. But I can't find how to print out fields that are custom fields (that is, we added them to TFS test-case record; they are not there out-of-the-box).

Is there a way to run the query and instead of getting a collection of records, just get the raw output strings that an SQL query would print to the screen, had I ran it directly on the DB?

Below is the code I use now. To get it to run you'd need to replace the "path to my DB" with the right path, and [A custom field] to the relevant one. The problem I am struggling with is how to print out the value of my custom field, hopefully without having to figure out where in the workitem it resides.

I did find that I have the value for my custom field here (path copied from the "watch" fiel):

`(new System.Collections.Generic.Mscorlib_DictionaryDebugView<int, object>(workitem.FieldData.m_latestData).Items[78]).Value`

But: I don't want to have to figure out, for each custom field, in what items[] location it is; also when trying to put the above in the Console.Writeline statement (or assign it first to a variable), it does not compile.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client;


namespace tfs_api_starter
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            // connect to a tfs collection
            var collectionUri = new Uri("https://path to my DB");
            var tfsCollection = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(collectionUri);

            // workitemStore object is used to query and update workitems
            var workitemStore = tfsCollection.GetService<WorkItemStore>();

            // query workitems
            var queryText = "SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], [System.State], [System.CreatedBy], [System.AreaPath], [System.IterationPath],  [My Custom field]  FROM WorkItemLinks WHERE Source.[System.WorkItemType] = 'Test Case' and (Target.[System.WorkItemType] = 'Test Execution' and Target.[System.CreatedDate] >= '2019-04-01T00:00:00.0000000') ";
            var workitemCollection = new Query(workitemStore, queryText).RunLinkQuery();

            foreach (var link in workitemCollection)
            {
                var workitem = workitemStore.GetWorkItem(link.TargetId);
                if (workitem.Type.Name == "Test Case")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}|{2}",
                        workitem.Id,
                        workitem.Title,
                        <my custom field value>);
                }
                if (workitem.Type.Name == "Test Execution")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}|{2}", workitem.Id, workitem.Type.Name, workitem.State);
                }

            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the result you are looking for ?

Comment: The actual data results from the query. What I get right now is a list of records with tons of information in them. I want just the values for the fields I queried for, for all the records that match the query criteria.

Comment: Could you please provide an image with the data you get and the data you are looking for.

Comment: See detailed explanation, with images, here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0q5lric3lfwum5y/Stackexchange_55782443_details.pdf?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

OK - got it:

All fields are accessible via the workitem.Fields structure.

You can get the field name:  workitem.Fields[i].Name
and the field value:          workitem.Fields[i].Value

To know how many fields exist: workitem.Fields.Count

If you know the name of the field you are looking for, you can get its value via workitem.Fields["FIELD_NAME"].Value

When you run the query as I have in the uestio, you get all the fields - regardless to what the SQL query text asked for.

Printing the header for all field names is now easy (note: I use "|" as field separator since TFS writes user names with a comma between last and first name):

Somewhere at the start, define a flag:

```
 bool first=true;
```

Then, after " if (workitem.Type.Name == "Test Case") "

have this:

```
 if (first) {
   // write the header with field names
    for (int i = 0; i < workitem.Fields.Count; i++) {
         Console.Write("{0}|", workitem.Fields[i].Name);
         Console.Write("\n");
         first = false;
        }
  }
```

And then print the values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < workitem.Fields.Count; i++)
{
    Console.Write("{0}|", workitem.Fields[i].Value);
}
```

And do something similar for Test Execution records - since the fields are different for this work item type.

It may actually be easier to separate the queries and (somehow) later to align the execution to the tests because (a) the query runs very slow as it is now and (b) the headers are different and the output gets messy with header lines for test cases and test execution records.